# Correlation higher than 1 when performing a multivariate meta-analysis with metaSEM

Tags: r, correlation, structural-equation-model, meta-analysis

I have simulated a dataset for a meta-analysis with 20 studies and 1000 observations each. Each participant presents data on two outcomes: a clinician rating (CR) and self-report (SR) that measure the same latent Illness (e.g., depression). The performance of each participant is measured at T0 and at EOT (Outcome).
Then, for each study I estimated the treatment effect, its standard error and the correlation between treatment effects using Seemingly Unrelated Regressions.

I performed the meta-analysis with metaSEM as: 
`msem <- metaSEM::meta(y=cbind(EstCR, EstSR), v=cbind(varCR, Cov, varSR), data=dat)`

This is the output:

> 95% confidence intervals: z statistic approximation (robust=FALSE) 
> Coefficients: 
> Estimate Std.Error    lbound    ubound z value Pr(>|z|)  
> Intercept1  3.015002  0.104818  2.809563  3.220441 28.7642   <2e-16 *** 
> Intercept2  3.153640  0.226073  2.710545  3.596734 13.9497   <2e-16 ***
> Tau2_1_1    0.012351  0.068944 -0.122776  0.147479  0.1792   0.8578    
> Tau2_2_1    0.190127  0.134189 -0.072879  0.453133  1.4169   0.1565    
> Tau2_2_2    0.478727  0.321296 -0.151002  1.108456  1.4900   0.1362
>
> Q statistic on the homogeneity of effect sizes: 49.16779
> Degrees of freedom of the Q statistic: 38
> P value of the Q statistic: 0.1059594
>
> Heterogeneity indices (based on the estimated Tau2):
> Estimate
> Intercept1: I2 (Q statistic)   0.0561
> Intercept2: I2 (Q statistic)   0.4683\
>
> Number of studies (or clusters): 20
> Number of observed statistics: 40
> Number of estimated parameters: 5
> Degrees of freedom: 35
> -2 log likelihood: 64.06444 
> OpenMx status1: 0 ("0" or "1": The optimization is considered fine.
> Other values may indicate problems.)

Then, I wanted to know the correlation between the effects on CR and SR, but I found a strange 2.47.

`cov2cor(vec2symMat(coef(msem, select="random")))`

To tackle this problem I set a higher lower bound for the between study heterogeneity, but it doesn't change too much.
How should I interpret this and where can I find the source of this "problem"?

```
msem <- metaSEM::meta(y=cbind(EstCR, EstSR), v=cbind(varCR, Cov, varSR), data=dat, RE.lbound = 1e-1)
summary(msem)
```

> Call:
> metaSEM::meta(y = cbind(EstCR, EstSR), v = cbind(varCR, Cov,
> varSR), data = dat, RE.lbound = 0.1)
>
> 95% confidence intervals: z statistic approximation (robust=FALSE) 
> Coefficients: 
> Estimate Std.Error   lbound   ubound z value Pr(>|z|)
> Intercept1  3.01466   0.12399  2.77165  3.25767 24.3145   <2e-16 *** 
> Intercept2  3.15429   0.25281  2.65879  3.64978 12.4770   <2e-16 *** 
> Tau2_1_1    0.10000   0.14807 -0.19021  0.39021  0.6754   0.4994
> Tau2_2_1    0.33946   0.26822 -0.18624  0.86517  1.2656   0.2057
> Tau2_2_2    0.73458   0.54414 -0.33191  1.80108  1.3500   0.1770
>
> Q statistic on the homogeneity of effect sizes: 49.16779 
> Degrees of freedom of the Q statistic: 38 
> P value of the Q statistic: 0.1059594
>
> Heterogeneity indices (based on the estimated Tau2):
> Estimate 
> Intercept1: I2 (Q statistic)   0.3251 
> Intercept2: I2 (Q statistic)   0.5748
>
> Number of studies (or clusters): 20 
> Number of observed statistics: 40 
> Number of estimated parameters: 5 
> Degrees of freedom: 35 
> -2 log likelihood: 65.08753  
> OpenMx status1: 0 ("0" or "1": The optimization is considered fine. 
> Other values may indicate problems.)

`cov2cor(vec2symMat(coef(msem, select="random")))`

> [,1]     [,2] 
> [1,] 1.000000 1.252487 
> [2,] 1.252487 1.000000